# Basic node.js express authentication not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am new to node.js authentication. I want to use passport, passport-local, to do some basic authentication. But when I try it, it always goes to authentication failed.

I am following this tutorial
http://www.sitepoint.com/local-authentication-using-passport-node-js/

This is what I have so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var qs = require('querystring');
var pg = require('pg');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
//var expressSession = require('express-session');


//app.use(expressSession({secret: 'mySecretKey', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

// in here I know I am supposed to connect to database, and check if the username,password is there, but for now, i'll just force it to return a user, like they exist.
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    console.log(1);  // does not even print this
    //return done(null, false);
    var r = done(null, {
      'username': username,
      'password': password
    });
    console.log(r);
    return r;
}));


/*
 * Visit the home page.
 */
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var dest = 'index.html';
    res.sendFile(dest, { root: __dirname });
});
/*
 * Login.
 */
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/loginSuccess.html',
        failureRedirect: '/loginFailure.html'
    })
);

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('My App started at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this?

Also can anyone explain how this basic authentication works, and what the serialize/deserialize functions are for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is lacking the [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware, which is required to parse incoming `POST` data.

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
...
```

Comment: Now it goes to success, but it also logs to console `body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option server.js:18:20`. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @omega it's documented [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#extended): you need to explicitly set the `extended` option. I've edited my answer accordingly.